# apache nifi recursively fetch files from web server directory

Tags: apache-nifi

I have web server with autoindex module that lists all files and folders. Something like that: [image]

How can i recursively fetch all files using Apache NiFi? I tried to use ListFTP/FetchFTP processors, but without any luck.

Can someone tell me what processors should i use for this task?

Comment: What do you mean with fetch recursively?
Normally List/Fetch pattern should work here to ingest all folders and underlying files whenever new ones appear.
Could you share the configuration you used for the ListFTP and FetchFTP?

Comment: i mean fetch not only files in this directory but from all subfolders. How List/Fetch would work here, since they r for local FS? this is a SS of a web browser, here is result of curl (had to cut it lil bit):
`
$ curl http://store01.dev/FILE/store/0002550267/
<html>
<head><title>Index of /FILE/store/0002550267/</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Index of /FILE/store/0002550267/</h1><hr><pre><a href="../">../</a>
<a href="00000001.TIF">00000001.TIF</a>                                       29-Dec-2016 18:36               35277
</pre><hr></body>
</html>
`

Comment: Sorry i dunno how to properly share processor config. Here is SS of how i did it: https://imgur.com/QdvAKcg

Comment: From which level do you want to fetch the files?
 * /
 * /FILE
 * FILE/store
... ?

Comment: from /FILE directory or even root / doesn't matter just need to get all files from every subfolder. Hence that's why need to do it recursively, cuz no idea how big is folder structure there

Answer (score 0):

As remote path you should specify the **root folder** from which you want to List/Fetch all files and sub folders.

In your case, you put /FILE/store/0002550267/ as remote path, so only files and folders in this directory will be picked up.

Change remote path to /File (or / if you want all files on the server) and you should see all files being listed.

Comment: Sorry for terrible explaining. Here live example: https://animorphsfanforum.com/fanart/2064/ 
each file can be downloaded with its own http url, It is not file system so List/Fetch won't work and not FTP so ListSFTP/FetchSFTP won't work either.
How to get all the files from root in this example?

Comment: But how to ignore the child folders in lists3 processor?